# linear regression mathematical equation and matrix-vector form from graph

Tags: linear-regression

I want to write the mathematical equation that represents these data points in the given graph below.

[image]

Knowing that this is not a linear regression, I want to continue the solution with $y = ax^2 + bx + c$, but I need to create a matrix-vector form using linear regression from the red line.

What exactly should I try? What is the mathematical equation that represents these data? Could it be about absolute value?

Comment: I think that quadratic function won’t give a good fit, since your data looks like graph of absolute value. Try transforming data, so it will look more like straight line, and apply linear regression to transformed data.

Comment: Thank you @Yalikesifulei, I know to write absolute value functions in `a |x-h| + k` form, how can I write it in the form you mentioned?

Comment: Subtract minimum $y$ value (approx -1 from your picture) from all $y$ values, so new minimum will be 0, and then apply transformation $(x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$ for points where $x<0$. Transformed data will look like straight line.

Comment: So @Yalikesifulei, I basically had 2 seperate equations to give me two different graphs such as `y-1 = a|x|` where `for x>0, y-1 = ax` and `for x<0, y-1 = -ax `. Should I apply linear regression to both of these seperate equations?

Comment: No, you have to apply linear regression to transformed data, get some line equation and apply reverse transformation.

Comment: I spent hours on this question @Yalikesifulei and I found the equation for the red line as `y=a|x-m|` and I also found a=0.1 , b=2.93 and m=0, no matter how hard I tried I still couldn't get the equation that would represent these blue data points. Could you help a little more, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118879/discussion-between-yalikesifulei-and-imageprocessingproblem).